# Algorithm for creating adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, random-graphs

Is it possible to create a graph ( represented in the form of Adjacency Matrix), when the number of nodes and the count of neighbors for each node is given?

Comment: Do you know the Erdős–Gallai Theorem? 
Also, you if know that the sequence of non-negative numbers ("count of neighbours") is indeed a degree sequence of some graph, this graph is not determined uniquely by this sequence!

Comment: graph can be random, only thing that's matter is that ith node have k neighbors. Order of nodes is not important.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Moreover, it is a very well known model, which produces a graph (a multigraph, to be precise) with a prescribed degree sequence (what you call in your question the count of neighbors). The only requirement is that this degree sequence is graphical, i.e., it satisfies the conditions of the [Erdős–Gallai theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem), mentioned in the comment. This model is called the configuration model, and it just randomly pairs the half-edges, whose total number is $2n$, where $n$ is the number of nodes in the graph. Note that since the pairing is completely random, self-loops and multiple edges are produced. The original source for the model is [this paper](http://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=agcYx2YAAAAJ&citation_for_view=agcYx2YAAAAJ%3au5HHmVD_uO8C), but I also advise, if possible, to check out Mark Newman Network: An Introduction book for mode details.